# Avoiding change line spacing in all display multiline equations

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing

I need to increase the line spacing with the `setspace` package but I **don't** want to affect the **all display math equations**. In other word, I want to set line spacing to `1` for all display math equations.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{align}
        x \\ y \\ z
    \end{align}
    \[
        \begin{bmatrix}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            4 & 5 & 6 \\
            7 & 8 & 9
        \end{bmatrix}
    \]
    \begin{gather}
        x \\ y \\ z
    \end{gather}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. We can use these commands before `\begin{document}`:

```
\everydisplay\expandafter{%
    \the\everydisplay
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont
}
```

Complete codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
%\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\everydisplay\expandafter{%
    \the\everydisplay
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont
}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{align}
        x \\ y \\ z
    \end{align}
    \[
        \begin{bmatrix}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            4 & 5 & 6 \\
            7 & 8 & 9
        \end{bmatrix}
    \]
    \begin{gather}
        x \\ y \\ z
    \end{gather}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

If we want to remove vertical space between equations:

```
\everydisplay\expandafter{%
    \the\everydisplay
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\selectfont
    \abovedisplayskip \displayskipstretch0pt
    \belowdisplayskip \displayskipstretch0pt
    \abovedisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch0pt
    \belowdisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch0pt
}
```